# Need help to make a simple Celsius converter

Tags: python, converters

I wanted to be able to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit. So after a bit of research I found a way to make it. Here's my code:

```
celsius = float(input('Enter degree Celsius: '))

fahrenheit = (celsius * 1.8) + 32
print('%0.1f degree Celsius is equal to %0.1f degree Fahrenheit' %(celsius,fahrenheit))

raw_input ("Press Enter To Close")
```

So my question is can I make this like simple little program. So like when I launch it it opens as a exe file, and then enter for an example 100 and hit OK, and underneath the button or something I get a answer.

Something like the picture. For the picture I used photoshop. [image: http://i.imgur.com/XvTEj0c.png]

Comment: use some gui, Like Tkinter

Comment: how do i combine Tkinter with my already wroten code? sorry if my question is dumb, as said im really new to Python :) Could you help me?

Comment: This question is much too broad - you should go and do some of your own research on Python GUI toolkits

Comment: If you are a beginner (and you say you are), wait a little before learning GUI ... Most suppose some knowledge of threading and synchronization

Comment: @SergeBallesta - I think you could whip this together using Tkinter without any knowledge of threading or synchronization. But I concur that Tkinter is currently beyond what Eric knows. He should learn about classes and modules and stuff before he tries learning Tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since pasting long code in comments is not possible, here's a very rough start:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter
import tkinter.simpledialog

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()


celsius = tkinter.simpledialog.askfloat(
  'Celsius converter',
  'Enter degree Celsius: '
)
fahrenheit = (celsius * 1.8) + 32
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(
  'Celsius converter',
  '%0.1f degree Celsius is equal to %0.1f degree Fahrenheit' % (celsius, fahrenheit)
)
```